# How can I call SaveChanges in entity framework without select scope_identity on an insert?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

We have a table that due to the volumes of data being inserted & read, calling select scope_identity times out. This results in the the insert being successful, but the calling application failing. (We determined it has to do with update statistics on the table).
Our ability to alter the table is limited, and as a solution, I have created two Ado.net calls to:

1. Call the insert without the select scope_identity (where we don't need the id)
2. An optional insert with the select scope_identity (where we need the new ID)

Is there a way I can reproduce this functionality with entity framework?
Is there a way to change the SaveChanges mechanism to perform the insert (it will always be an insert) without including the Select SCOPE_IDENTITY in the insert statement?

Thanks

Comment: I have a gut feeling that this can not be a robust solution and that you should look for strategies to handle bulk inserts.